# How to building pretty URLs to reflect category hierarchy?

Tags: url-rewriting, urls, rewrite-rules

At the moment, this is how I access brands (custom post type) on my page:

`http://example.com/<base>/<brand>`

I would like to access brands like this:

`http://example.com/<base>/<category>/<sub_category>/<brand>`

This is reasonable, bacause each `<brand>` lives in a `<sub_category>` so I'd like to have it reflected in the URLs (and later, breadcrumbs).

The permalink on the admin edit page for brands is also `http://example.com/<base>/<brand>`.

How can I build URLs that I'm after - so that `<brand>` is prepended with `<category>` and `<sub_category>` ? What are my options ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change the **`Settings -> Permalink`** to Custom Structure **`/%category%/%postname%/`**

Now while editing the post, check only the **`subcategory`** and now the parent category is nested within the URL automatically.